# Parse thru XML using a URL not on a Windows Server

Tags: xml, web-services, lotus-notes, lotus

I am wanting to write a scheduled agent, that calls a URL, which returns XML and will then create new documents in the database based on the XML data.

I know that LotusScript offers some classes that allows you to parse thru XML, but it requires the XML to be stored in a file.

I also know, that you can use some OLE objects in order to call the URL, but that only works on Windows machines. My agent however, would run on a Linux machine.

Is there a Java class or example code out there, that I could use in order to achieve this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's plenty of support in Java for [retrieving data using the URLConnection class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html) or the [Apache HTTP Components](http://hc.apache.org/), and [mulitple techniques available for parsing XML](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/05/parsing-xml-using-dom-sax-and-stax-parser-in-java.html). Note: you might run into problems with Java security on this, which is above and beyond the normal security concerns and controls in the Agent Manager that LotusScript is plugged into, do you might have to [fiddle around with Java policy settings on the server](http://lekkimworld.com/2013/06/20/java_in_notes_domino_explained_on_java_security_and_how_it_relates_to_notes_domino.html).

Comment: Hello Richard, thank you for your response, I appreciate it. I will take a look at the links and see, if I can figure it out. You would have thought, with Notes and Domino version 9, IBM would have implemented a way to consume URLs. But I guess the focus was on XPages rather than LotusScript.

Comment: They did put some effort into consuming web services in lotusscript, but AFAIK they never exposed the URL retriever from that package to make useful for non-SOAP  data. It would have been useful. I spent a lot of time wrestling with winhttp, bit of course that's no help for other platforms.